# Fetching 1 millions of Data From Mysql using springboot for perfoming bussiness logic

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am in a situation of getting Very Huge Amount of Data from Mysql to my springboot Application.

So is there any preferable way to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Why do you need 10 million records in your application?

Comment: Those data will be used in throughout the application.So fetching it once will reduce the no.of.hits to the mysql right...

Comment: This sounds really wrong to me. Are you expecting to actually use all or close to all the rows? If not this is a huge waste or resources.
Also if you change any data and want to write it back JPA will reload it anyway unless you are doing everything in one huge session which would be another huge PITA and make the application really slow.
If you need to speed up random access and your MySql database doesn't cut it, I would look into other stores like in memory databases or document databases depending on your needs.

Please carify what your actual requirements are.

Comment: If you want to show data in table, you can use pagination by using `Pageable` object , Also you can implement fetch type lazy. If you are using data for export report you should use spring batch.

Answer (score 1):

The big question is: What do you want to do with those 10million records? 
JPA is mainly good for loading a limited object graph that you then manipulate and flush it back into the database.
This only works for a rather limited data volume well. 
With large amounts of data the overhead become prohibitive and the benefits often vanish.

Without any further knowledge I'd recommend stepping away from JPA and consider more low level ways to access the data. 
Especially Springs [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) often comes in handy.
And there if applicable the methods using a [`RowCallbackHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html) since it doesn't assume that you convert the `ResultSet` to anything else but just process it, e.g. in order write out the data to some text file.

Another thing to look at is [Spring Batch](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch) when processing large amounts of data.

Comment: Based on the 10 millions records only the remaining application works.we didn't know which record it need.so instead of getting to mysql service each time once we get all the data from the mysql then we can process locally right.That's y i am searching like that..

Comment: Are you processing 10 million records on the first page of the application itself?

Comment: @Shivakumar it is not for UI bro...

Comment: @vishnumurali it seems that you would like to use jpa as an in-memory cache. ORMs in general are not particularly suitable for this task because they are slow and have a huge memory footprint. RDBMSs are designed to allow quick lookup and retrieval of data. Let mysql do what it was designed for and cache data only when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

1. 10 million Records cannot be shown in the UI at a time for User to Comprehend. I suggest you keep the number with respect to the number of records you need on each page through the UI Navigation.
2. If the 10 million records are to do a transaction again in the UI, I suggest you keep the transacted data in those rows itself while saving so that you need not iterate again.
3. You can identify the unique columns and configure a composite primary key. It will decrease the querying time.
4. Minimizing the Joins. If you are Joining too many tables, reduce the number of joins. Do not Over Normalize the Database.
5. If you are saving images in the database in some format, move them to the File system, save the file system path and Name of the image in your database.
6. Reduce the Number of Columns. Ex: Out of 100 Columns, you might need only 5 or 10 columns to be displayed in the UI at any point of time, save those in one table and remaining 95-90 in another table. Observe the length of the query.
7. Use a connection pooling mechanism.

Comment: it doesn't need for UI .For processing the input i need those data.

Comment: Do not process the input after fetching the database. Keep the processed data in the DB while you are saving or updating so that you need not perform any processing again. Point no. 2

Comment: @vishnumurali, any comments?

Comment: i am just figured out there is a tool called Speedment which is Java8 based ORM tool which helps to retrieve data in very fast manner.

Comment: Okay. Let us know if it works. However, it is important to identify the reasons why you might need such huge data. That's the root.

Comment: It's working fine till now @shivakumar .it will fetch 1MILLION records within 2 to 3 seconds based on the system configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If loading 1 million rows needs 2-3 sec, but loading 10 million rows needs 24 mins, then I think it's a memory problem. JPA maintain a lot of additional ino about the persistent objects, so as long as the objects are inside a transaction the memory need could be much higher than is actually needed for storing the data itself.

So load the data *outside of a transaction* in smaller chunks (like 1 million), then manually assembly them into one collection.
If you need these records for some kind of calculation, then that's all.
If you also need to make changes in them, you need to handle the modifications and saves manually.

Although I still believe we can find a better solution if you share the **original problem** with us...